# .innerHTML -> console.log shows formatting but DOM element doesn't

Tags: javascript, console.log

```
        let parser = new DOMParser();
        let OFPXML = parser.parseFromString(json, "application/xml");
        Formats = OFPXML.querySelector('Formats');
        XML1 = Formats.children[1].innerHTML;
        console.log(XML1); // This retains linebreaks
        document.getElementById('text_from_XML_node_here').innerHTML = XML1;  // This does not retain them.
```

Console.log shows the text with linebreaks but the DOM element removed them all.

This is a low-priority question as I am just learning and experimenting with things.

Comment: What is `OFPXML`?

Comment: Can you please provide the value of `XML1`? @Spectric I believe it must be another element.

Comment: If by line breaks you mean carriage returns and/or linefeeds, browsers will convert them into spaces. If you mean actual `<br>` tags, perhaps they are encoded as `.innerText`?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line breaks are not shown in the rendered HTML element. When DOM elements are rendered, raw newlines like `\n` are ignored. If you want line breaks explicitly to show, you have the following options:

- Change the element to a `<pre>`
- Replace newlines in your XML1 variable with `<br />`

Comment: pre tags worked!  Good to know!